# Problem in hiding whole bottom navigation bar in android studio

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I have several fragments in activity and i want to show bottom navigation to to only specific fragment not all. Bottom navigation has 5 menu items navigating to different fragments. I want to hide all items in Bottom Naviagtion that is hide whole bottom navigation.But i dont know how to hide the whole bottom navigation.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom navigation forms a part of your activity, so while switching fragment, control goes to your activtiy, at that time you will need to hide the bottom bar layout by setting its visibilty to `GONE` and make it `VISIBLE` again when it goes to other tabs.

Also According to your question if bottom bar is hidden then there are no tabs  to click, you might need to override `onBackPressed` to go back to previous tab, and maybe press twice to exit the app